# Cpanel File manager Extract button disable

Tags: cpanel, nsfilemanager

Today i found extraction of zip file seems disabled in cpanel **File Manager**.Yesterday it was working fine and i had extracted one file .I had uploaded a big file of size 472MB.but then uploading got cancelled and From then  I am facing the problem.

[image]

What is the reason behind the strange behaviour of cpanel file manager.?

And what is the solution to this problem..?

I really want the extract button enabled because Upload on server using Filezilla is very time consuming..

Answer (score 0):

By default the icon is grayed out if no file is selected, make sure that's not the case.

If it's selected and it's like that then you might consider checking with your hosting provider, if you're the administrator of the server then go ahead and run

```
/scripts/upcp
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to select the file which need to be extracted. Extract button will automatically appear if you select any zip file from your directory.
[image]